# Simple typescript file gives exports is not defined error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I making a simple typescript application and it is throwing error step by step like,

Code:

**app.ts**

```
function add(a,b){
    return a + b;
}

const result = add('10','5');

console.log(result);
```

**Error 1:**

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'result'.

**Solution 1:**
Included `export {}` in `app.ts` like,

```
 export {}
 function add(a,b){
        return a + b;
    }

    const result = add('10','5');

    console.log(result);
```

which also compile the **js** file like,

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
var result = add('10', '5');
console.log(result);
```

This results in error at browser like,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at app.js:2

Please help me how can I fix this issue? Also added `tsconfig.json` file but that also didn't help it throws error like,

> /@types/express/index.d.ts' not found.

Typescript version: **Version 3.8.3**

Comment: Are you trying to paste this code into your browser's console by chance?

Comment: @sylvanaar, No I am not into browser.. I am running the code only in terminal .

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error in simple typescript app too.In order to solve that after searching for an hour, I came up with this solution:

adding this line of code to  index.html file.This makes the error go away.

```
 <script>var exports = {};</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply export it as it is:

```js
function add(a: string, b: string) {
    return a + b;
}

const result = add('10','5');

export { result };
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have the error in the first place might be because TS is picking up the compiled file as well and is assuming the result is being redefined as it sees 2 files declaring the same global variable.

Scripts create global variables when you use `var` (to which the `const` may transpile to) and `function`. Modules don't do that.

TypeScript assumes the file is a script if it doesn't have export or import statements. So adding the `export {}` makes the error go away.

However, you're using the default module system in TS, which is `CommonJS`, so the file is transpiled assuming there's an `exports` object in it's scope. That would be the case in `NodeJS`, but not the browser.

If you change the tsconfig.json to have `module: "ES2015"` or `module: "ESNext"`, the compiler will use import and export statements instead, which work in the browser if the entry point is defined with `<script type="module" src="...`.